# Mysql Archive old data

Tags: mysql, archive

I want to archive from mysql old data (more than a year) to a file and remove the same information from database. This way I only have in my database data from the last year.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Provide some more information. Is there any way in your tables to identify that at what time it was added?

Comment: Do you want to do that for all your tables, or some specific tables?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -e "select * from your_table where `date` < now() - interval 1 year" -u myuser -pxxxxxxxxx mydatabase > mydumpfile.txt

delete from your_table where `date` < now() - interval 1 year
```